# How to store token in DB Other than jdbcTokenStore?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Right now i have this oAUth2 token store configuration

```
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
```

I want to store my token in database so i need some other custom implementation to store & retrieve token. I checked `jdbcTokenStore` but it need `DataStore` and i am using cassandra so its not possible to pass DataStore instance. So is there any other solution apart of `jdbcTokenStore` to store toke in db?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way is to create your own class that implements `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore`.

You may refer to the `JdbcTokenStore` implementation on how they do things.

Comment: You can refer to [Cassandra OAuth2 Token Store for Spring Security OAuth2](https://github.com/Mert-Z/spring-oauth2-cassandra-token-store) project for a `TokenStore` implementation backed by Cassandra.